# How to set entire object?

Tags: javascript, mobx

```
import {observable} from 'mobx';

let obj = observable({foo: 5});
```

This creates an observable object with a property called `foo`. If I do,

```
obj.foo = 9;
```

The change will be tracked as expected.

However, what I want to overwrite *all* the values of `obj`? How can I do that? Like, how can I set it to `{bar: 7}`?

```
obj = {bar: 7}
```

Obviously won't work, because I've just replaced it with a non-observable.

```
Object.assign(obj, {bar:7})
```

Won't get rid of the `foo` property.

Is there a utility method in `mobx` somewhere for setting the whole object?

Comment: I don't think that's possible unless you register it in some way beforehand (it actually is registered by calling observable I believe) because references cannot be manipulated directly in JavaScript. However, the `Object.assign` call does indeed mutate the first argument and should trigger proxies.

Comment: In mobx, adding new keys to an observable object will not trigger updates. You can use `extendObservable(target, props)` to introduce new observable properties to an object.

There is more information on this here [https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html#-object-somenewprop-value-is-not-picked-up]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a way to do that in `mbox` but in `javascript` native; simply remove all old properties using `delete` keyword before you assign the new properties:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  delete obj[key]; 
});

Object.assign(obj, {bar: 7});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably recommend writing your own utility method if there isn't one already. It could possibly look something like this;

```
function bulk_set_observable(obj, replacements) {
    for (let key in replacements) {
        obj[key] = replacements[key];
    }
}
```

Then to use it, you just provide the observable as the first argument and an object containing all of the keys and values you wish to replace.